# Hey, so im creating a APi which is integrated with a Discord bot. However when i wanted to send a message to a channel it gave me a runtime error

Tags: python, api, discord.py, fastapi, uvicorn

Due to the Runtime error, ive tried switching to using discord webhooks to send my message and this works but i also need to add reactions to the message through the bot but this isnt working because when i use discord webhooks, it returns no data to me and I need the message ID to fetch it and add reactions, that is if none of those functions give me Runtime errors.

Full Traceback:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 407, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 271, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 118, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/home/container/bot.py", line 345, in test
    m = await channel.send(embed=embed)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1561, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 624, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 467, in _request
    with timer:
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 701, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

The code I am using for this API call:

```py
class ClanCreateBody(BaseModel):
    clan_tag: str
    user_id: int
    username: str

        
@app.get("/createclan/")
async def test(body: ClanCreateBody, AuthToken: str | None = Header(default=None)):
    if AuthToken == "testtoken":
        pass
    else:
        return {"Invalid": "Token"}
    
    check_emoji = bool(emoji.get_emoji_regexp().search(body.clan_tag))
    if check_emoji:
        return {"Invalid": "Emojis are not allowed in clan tags"}

    if not body.clan_tag:
        return {"Invalid": "There is no clan tag"}

    # Check they don't already have a clan
    has_clan, clan = await bot.id_has_clan_both(body.user_id)
    if has_clan:
        if clan.role_id == -1:
            return {"Invalid": "User is already in a clan"}
        else:
            return {"Invalid": "User is already in a clan"}

    # Check this clan name isn't already taken
    name_is_taken = await bot.clan_name_is_taken(body.clan_tag)
    if name_is_taken:
        return {"Invalid": "This clan name is already taken!"}

    # It's good to create
    channel = bot.get_channel(secret_file["staff_channel_id"])
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Clan creation request",
        description=f"Clan name: `{body.clan_tag}`\nRequester: {body.username}\n\n"
        f"To accept this please react with a tick.\n"
        f"To reject this please react with a cross.",
        color=embed_color,
        timestamp=discord.utils.utcnow(),
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{body.user_id} : Sent from web")
    m = await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await m.add_reaction("✅")
    await m.add_reaction("❎")

    await bot.db.pending_clans.insert(
        {
            "_id": body.clan_tag.lower(),
            "name": body.clan_tag,
            "role_id": -1,
            "clan_points": 0,
            "total_koth_wins":0,
            "total_roam_wins":0,
            "total_maze_wins":0,       
            "leader_id": body.id,
            "members": [],
            "co_leaders": [],
            "pending_invites": [],
            "pending_message_id": m.id,
            "created_at": datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%-I:%M %p %m/%d/%Y"),
            "discord_invite": "Set with !clansetdiscord",
            "video_url": "!Set with !clannew",
            "channel_id": None,
        }
    )


    for member in staff:
        try:
            sname = secret_file["server_name"]
            await member.send(embed = discord.Embed(title= f"New Clan Application on {sname}",description=f"{body.user_id} wants to make **{body.clan_tag}** [Click Here]({m.jump_url}) to accept/decline that.",color=embed_color))
        
        except (discord.HTTPException, discord.Forbidden):
            pass
    
    return {"Status": "Request sent"}
```

I tried to directly call the discordAPI and sending my message straight through that and bypassing the discord.py function but I could not figure it out and thought it would give me the same error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I found a solution, for those of you wondering you are able to create a middleman async function like this:

```
async def sendMsg(channel, embed):
m = await channel.send(embed = embed)
return m
```

This works in terms of executing that function however depending on what you're doing other issues in terms of running commands can occur with the main Discord Bot loop which I may need to post another question about haha.